# Half-Round Trim on Armor

Tags: modeling, extrude

Trying to add a half round trim around the front surfaces of a piece of modeled armor. Found videos on using inset and extrusion, but I cant figure out how to profile the extrusion into a half circle:

[image]

Alternatively, I've tried shrinkwrapping a half round pipe to the surface, but cant figure out how to make it follow the edge without meticulously rotating curves to follow the edges:

[image]

Feel like there has to be a better way to do this. Any feedback would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell what you want to do, but It sounds like you want to make a round "border". In that case, Beveling is the tool for the job.

Select an edge that you need to round, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. Move your mouse to control the depth of the bevel, and scroll to adjust the segments of the bevel, sort of like its resolution. There are a lot of settings that you can change. You can even bevel multiple edges at the same time by selecting them all and doing the same thing. Additionally, there is a bevel modifier that can bevel every single edge.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks, Eric!

Comment: @Winghead88 .. if an answer has worked for you, you can mark it as accepted, with the tick.